# Why does VS Code break my Markdown fenced code blocks?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

I'm creating a markdown document with some CSharp code blocks. Here's a sample:

````
Next, it feeds the strings to the regular expression matcher to produce a sequence of matches.

```csharp
        let patternMatch = azimuthEncoderRegex.Match(message)
```
````

In the editor, this seems to be working nicely, like so:
[image]

As you can see, the code is formatted as expected and shows up correctly formatted in the preview window (not shown).

Now, when I save my file, the above text instantly changes to this:
[image]

If I use search-and-replace to change all the code specifiers back, the same thing happens. This breaks the code formatting!! The entire file is also re-flowed to remove all the line breaks I put in (that may be a clue).

UPDATE: I noticed that all of the reference-style hyperlinks were also removed from the end of the document, causing data loss.

WTF? Why is VS-Code doing this? I've tried disabling the Markdown extensions and the same thing happens. Any ideas, please?

Comment: Maybe this is caused by any other plugin? I just tried it on my site with VSCode 1.31.1 on Windows 10. Your described phenomen doesn´t happen there.

Comment: @Sebastian It never used to do this for me, either. Perhaps I've set some crazy setting, but I have no idea what would result in this behaviour.

Comment: I can prevent this from happening by setting `"editor.FormatOnSave": false`. So it looks like Format-on-Save is the culprit. But why would this break my markdown code blocks?

Comment: I've narrowed this down to a plugin called Pandoc Format (a code formatter for Markdown). Issue raised. https://github.com/monofon/pandoc-format/issues/3

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by a change in settings.json for VS Code:

```
{
    "pandocFormat.command": "pandoc --standalone --atx-headers --wrap=auto --columns=80 -f markdown-auto_identifiers -t markdown-simple_tables-multiline_tables-grid_tables-auto_identifiers-fenced_code_attributes --reference-links"
}
```

Thanks and credit to [monofon](https://github.com/monofon/pandoc-format/issues/3#issuecomment-464429219) (the author of the VS Code extension, based on Pandoc) for [steering me to this solution](https://github.com/monofon/pandoc-format/issues/3#issuecomment-464429219).